# Why is FetchSize setting in ODP.NET affected by connection pooling?

Tags: oracle, odp.net

A number of blogs and sites mention increasing FetchSize of OracleDataReader to improve performance when fetching big volumes of data (e.g. thousands of rows). There are some documented experiments with exact numbers on this like: http://metekarar.blogspot.com/2013/04/performance-improvement-for-odpnet.html

Trying to replicate these results, I have created a very similar sample application that does such data fetching several times with varying fetch sizes. Strangely, unless the connection pooling is explicitly disabled (e.g. in the connection string), the increase/decrease of FetchSize stops having any effect. When the pooling is disabled though, it's clear that the FetchSize can improve the performance (the more records, the bigger the effect).

Might this be a bug in the particular version of ODP.NET (I am using 2.112.1.0) or this is a universal weird behavior, which in practice removes the possibility to optimize FetchSize per query.

What's the logical link between connection pooling and FetchSize, when the FetchSize is set on the command or the reader (and not on the connection)? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you get final solution using `FetchSize`? My table has 40.0000 rows and, has 100 columns. ***SELECT CAMPO1, ..., CAMPO100 FROM TABLA*** is slow, more 15s.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this unexpected behavior is limited to the following conditions:
1) The SELECT statement is exactly the same
2) The pooling is ON
3) The self-tuning is ON

Only in those conditions the first time the FetchSize is set, it gets somehow cached by ODP.NET and attempts to change it don't work.

Comment: HOw can I put  ***The pooling is ON and The self-tuning is ON*** in ODP.NET ?